# I need guidance on how to convert the creation of a matrix via python/numpy to javascript

Tags: javascript, opencv, transformation

I need to align 2 images with opencv.js

I'm attempting to find a way around the problem found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62744310/opencv-js-issue-with-findtransformecc-criteria). So I am trying [this approach](https://www.learnopencv.com/image-alignment-feature-based-using-opencv-c-python/).

I'm having issues trying to recreate (and calculate) the python numpy transformation matrix in javascript.

Here is the python:

```
image_baseline_keypoints = np.float32([kpv_image_baseline[m.queryIdx].pt for m in matches[:number_of_matches]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2);
image_keypoints = n.float32([kpv_image[m.trainIdx].pt for m in matches[:number_of_matches]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2);

(note: the article [linked above][2] has another way of creating the matrix via numpy as well. )
```

**what is the appropriate approach to doing the same thing in javascript?**  is it to use numjs (attempting it next but if possible i don't want to bring in another library)?

here is the overall JS code:

```
    function Align_img2() {

        let image_baseline = cv.imread(imgElement_Baseline);
        let image = cv.imread('imageChangeup');

        let image_baseline_gray = new cv.Mat();
        let image_gray = new cv.Mat();

        //get size of baseline image
        var image_baseline_width = image_baseline.cols;
        var image_baseline_height = image_baseline.rows;

        //resize image to baseline image
        let image_baseline_dimensions = new cv.Size(image_baseline_width, image_baseline_height);
        cv.resize(image, image, image_baseline_dimensions, cv.INTER_AREA);

        // Convert images to grayscale
        cv.cvtColor(image_baseline, image_baseline_gray, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        cv.cvtColor(image, image_gray, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        // Initiate detector
        var orb = new cv.ORB(10000);
        var kpv_image_baseline = new cv.KeyPointVector();
        var kpv_image = new cv.KeyPointVector();
        var descriptors_image_baseline =new cv.Mat();
        var descriptors_image =new cv.Mat();
        var image_baseline_keypoints=new cv.Mat();
        var image_keypoints =new cv.Mat();

        // find the keypoints with ORB
        orb.detect(image_baseline_gray, kpv_image_baseline);
        orb.detect(image_gray, kpv_image);

        // compute the descriptors with ORB
        orb.compute(image_baseline_gray, kpv_image_baseline, descriptors_image_baseline);
        orb.compute(image_gray, kpv_image, descriptors_image);

        // Debug to verify key points found
        //let color = new cv.Scalar(0,255,0, 255);
        //cv.drawKeypoints(image_baseline_gray, kpv_image_baseline, image_baseline_keypoints, color);
        //cv.drawKeypoints(image_gray, kpv_image, image_keypoints, color);
        //console.log(image_baseline_keypoints);
        //console.log(image_keypoints);

        // find matches
        let bf = new cv.BFMatcher(cv.NORM_HAMMING, 1);
        // Match descriptors
        let matches = new cv.DMatchVector();
        bf.match(descriptors_image_baseline, descriptors_image, matches);

        // Debug to verify matches found
        //var matches_img = new cv.Mat();
        //cv.drawMatches(image_baseline_gray, kpv_image_baseline, image_gray, kpv_image, matches, matches_img, color);
        //console.log(matches_img);

        // calculate transformation matrix
        number_of_matches = 10;
        /* 
        image_baseline_keypoints = np.float32([kpv_image_baseline[m.queryIdx].pt for m in matches[:number_of_matches]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2);
        image_keypoints = np.float32([kpv_image[m.trainIdx].pt for m in matches[:number_of_matches]]).reshape(-1, 1, 2);
        */

        //note: np => nj in numjs
        image_baseline_keypoints = nj.float32([kpv_image_baseline[m.queryIdx].pt for (m in matches)]).reshape(-1, 1, 2);
        image_keypoints = nj.float32([kpv_image[m.trainIdx].pt for (m in matches)]).reshape(-1, 1, 2);

        // Calculate Homography
        var h = new cv.Mat();
        h = cv.findHomography(image_baseline_keypoints, image_keypoints);

        // Warp image to baseline_image based on homography
        var dst = new cv.Mat();
        cv.warpPerspective(image_gray, dst, h, (image_baseline_gray.shape[1], image_baseline_gray.shape[0]));
        cv.imshow('imageChangeup', dst);

        matches_img.delete();
        matches.delete();
        bf.delete();
        orb.delete();
        kpv_image_baseline.delete();
        kpv_image.delete();
        descriptors_image_baseline.delete();
        descriptors_image.delete();
        image_baseline_keypoints.delete();
        image_keypoints.delete();
        image_baseline_gray.delete();
        image_gray.delete();
        h.delete();
        dst.delete();
    };
```

Comment: I viewed the source you have mentioned , and it seems it is easy for you to do same approach by looking the cpp sample code . and now there is no need to add numjs to your project1   // Extract location of good matches
  std::vector<Point2f> points1, points2;
  for( size_t i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++ 
  {
    points1.push_back( keypoints1[ matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
    points2.push_back( keypoints2[ matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
  }

Comment: HAMED - I posted below as it was too big for comment and formatting wouldn't work.  I'm doing what you suggested (I think) and I'm having difficulty finding queryIdx.  any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately , opencvjs doc is AWFUL ! actually there is nothing to be named as doc !
cv.findHomography method has 3 arguments . where two first ones must be matArray . you must convert your pointA and pointB to matArray by calling : `cv.matFromArray(number_of_cols_pointsA,2,cv.CV_32F,pointsA)`
and here , "2" is array dimention .
and CV_32F referes to float32 type mat .
and for the third argument of `findHomography` you can use `cv.RANSAC`

Comment: HAMED, you rock.  I'm through that hurdle thanks to you.  Now i'm up against the last call warpPerspective() with an uncaught exception.  trying to figure it out now.  I updated the code below.  thank you very much for your help.  I've been stuck on this for a while and was looking for alternatives when you gave me hope that opencv might still be a fit.

Comment: I suspect that the homography returned isn't yet valid for warpPerspective() even though it didn't error out.  It looks valid in console.log (copied a bit of it below). If I use any other simple matrix for the third argument it works fine such `let srcTri = cv.matFromArray(4, 1, cv.CV_32FC2, [56, 65, 368, 52, 28, 387, 389, 390]);
            let dstTri = cv.matFromArray(4, 1, cv.CV_32FC2, [0, 0, 300, 0, 0, 300, 300, 300]);
            let M = cv.getPerspectiveTransform(srcTri, dstTri);)`

Comment: I suspect the problem is `let mat_A = cv.matFromArray(points_A.length, 2, cv.CV_32F, points_A);`   --am I not getting argument 1 correctly using .length? or is argument 2 wrong--i tried points_B[0].length but it's undefined.... or do I need cv.CV_32FC2 as argument 3 (type)?  I'm also wondering if I'm the only person that has tried homography with javascript on opencv :-)

Comment: HAMED, I updated the question below.  I really want to solve this--but I am again out of ideas given the lack of opencv.js docs or warpperspective examples out there.